# I have an issue while integrating the Facebook to an android app

Tags: java, android, facebook-sdk-3.1

I have make a simple test application that will display the list of friends . But the problem is the list is empty . I saw some where on the web that we have to actually fill up all the formalities for registering the FB app , and even upload the app on the google play . But I just want to test it out , isn't there a simpler way , I mean just for testing purpose ?

and also I have seen that only friends that use the same app will be displayed . But even this does not happen for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to new facebook sdk, you need to submit your app for review if you are publishing anything. after facebook approval you can upload picture by using any login. you can check this link for review process

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/

https://github.com/sauce/guide/wiki/Facebook's-approval-process

and for friend list please refer answer in below link

[Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)